# How to resolve Pimcore errors causing denial of service at hosting provider?

Tags: pimcore

Our hosting provider has set an instance of the Pimcore demo package as the basis for our website. There are two problems which may or may not be linked: excessive resource usage when visiting the home page (resulting in the provider limiting/denying access) and FFmpeg ("Sorry message" or thumbnail displays but video does not load). We'd like to solve both problems but access is the main one.

The providers are asking for more information without saying what they want, so I am wondering if the sequence of error log entries in [this file](http://codeway.biz/Error_Log_Entries.txt) rings any bells with you.

System cache write lock?

Thank you

Ian Russell

Answer (score 0):

first of all, Mysqli is not supported anymore by Pimcore, please use PDO instead (https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/1236). This should take care of error messages you have in your error log.

Secondly, use Redis for caching, default mysql cache can be resource-heavy. You can read how to enable Redis here:
https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Development_Tools_and_Details/Cache/Custom_Cache_Backends.html

In the case of ffmpeg - didn't it get answered in this google group post already? In short - make sure ffmpeg version is correct and Pimcore can find it's executable.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pimcore/WxZ9OqbKf4k

If you can't get your hosting provider to update ffmpeg for whole system, try to install it in your home directory and point Pimcore to your ffmpeg binary.

Hope this helps,

kubaplas